# Parameter added by groovy to jenkins job not visible on build page

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have a script that adds a parameter to my jobs under a view. It nearly works, but the newly added parameter only appears on the 'configure' page of the job and doesn't show up when I try to build the job.
The problem is somewhere about saving, because when i try to add an other parameter the previously added prameter disappears even from the 'configure' page.

My code is the following:

```
import hudson.model.*
import jenkins.model.*

param_type = "choice";
param_name = "param";
param_value = ["ch1", "ch2"] as String[]; 
param_description = "description"
views = "test1"

def jobNames = [];
for(choice in views.split(",")){
  Hudson.instance.getView(choice).items.each() { 
    jobNames.add(it.fullDisplayName) 
  }
}

for(item in Hudson.instance.items) {
  for(jobName in jobNames){
    if(item.name.equalsIgnoreCase(jobName))
    {  

      def paramDefProp = item.getProperty(ParametersDefinitionProperty.class);
      if (paramDefProp != null) {
        def parameters = new ArrayList<ParameterDefinition>();
        parameters += paramDefProp.getParameterDefinitions();
        switch(param_type){
          case "string":
          parameters.add(new StringParameterDefinition(param_name, param_value, param_description));
          case "boolean":
          parameters.add(new BooleanParameterDefinition(param_name, param_value, param_description));
          case "choice":
          parameters.add(new ChoiceParameterDefinition(param_name, param_value, param_description));
        }
        item.addProperty(new ParametersDefinitionProperty(parameters));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried Jenkins.save(),  Jenkins.reload(), item.save(), item.updateTransientActions() in the for loop, but neither of these helped.
Any ideas?

Comment: I have similar code but I'm doing `job.removeProperty( ParametersDefinitionProperty.class )` and then `job.addProperty( new ParametersDefinitionProperty( newParamsDef ) )`. Otherwise you might end up with multiple `ParametersDefinitionProperty` instances, but Jenkins only reads the 1st one. If this works for you too, I'll turn this into an answer.

Comment: Thank for the tip @zett42 i tried it but didnn't help. I got the very same result.

Comment: In which context are you doing this? Script console, pipeline job, ...? What kind of jobs are you trying to modify?

Comment: I'm using the script in script soncole and trying to modify freestyle jobs.

Comment: Ok, I'm doing this as part of a pipeline job. Will try to reproduce using script console when I find some time later.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet works for me. Just change a bit on the `for loop`

```
for(item in Jenkins.instance.allItems)
```

and

add the removing old property

```
item.removeProperty(paramDefProp)
```

```
import hudson.model.*
import jenkins.model.*

param_type = "choice";
param_name = "param";
param_value = ["ch1", "ch2"] as String[]; 
param_description = "description"
views = "test1"

def jobNames = [];
for(choice in views.split(",")){
  Hudson.instance.getView(choice).items.each() { 
    jobNames.add(it.fullDisplayName) 
  }
}

for(item in Jenkins.instance.allItems) {
  for(jobName in jobNames){
    if(item.name.equalsIgnoreCase(jobName))
    {  

      def paramDefProp = item.getProperty(ParametersDefinitionProperty.class);
      if (paramDefProp != null) {
        def newParameters = new ArrayList<ParameterDefinition>();
        newParameters += paramDefProp.getParameterDefinitions();
        switch(param_type){
          case "string":
          newParameters.add(new StringParameterDefinition(param_name, param_value, param_description));
          case "boolean":
          newParameters.add(new BooleanParameterDefinition(param_name, param_value, param_description));
          case "choice":
          newParameters.add(new ChoiceParameterDefinition(param_name, param_value, param_description));
        }
        item.removeProperty(paramDefProp)
        item.addProperty(new ParametersDefinitionProperty(newParameters));
      }
    }
  }
}
```